# AES_DECRYPT for login JFrame code not working

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

I am having problems understand something related to AES_DECRYPT. I made a test database in SQL and table tblKorisnici in it. Field I am having problem with is sifra in which is stored data using AES_ENCRYPT via MySQL.

Problem is: I want Application to check korisnik and sifra, if both match lblInfo should display text was login data entered correct, is there a user with given korisnik and sifra in table.

```
    private void btnPotvrdiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String sql = "SELECT korisnik, AES_DECRYPT(sifra, 'sometext'), ime, prezime, pozicija FROM tblKorisnici WHERE korisnik = ? AND sifra = ?";
    try {
        konekcija = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lpa", "root", "");
        pst = konekcija.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtKorisnik.getText());
        pst.setString(2, pasSifra.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            lblInfo.setText("Login success");
        }
        else {
            lblInfo.setText("Wrong");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

But, somehow, I can't make it work. korisnik, sifra, ime, prezime and pozicija are fields in table, only sifra is encrypted using AES_ENCRYPT and "sometext" as encryption key.

I don't get any errors, just not working as intended. Probably something with sifra decryption because when I try sifra field with no encryption with data everything works.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will check those functions you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `WHERE` clause.  You are trying to compare the encrypted value of `sifra` to the unencrypted value of `pasSifra`. You need to either encrypt `pasSifra` (preferred) or decrypt `sifra` in the where clause.

Try changing your query to this:

```
sql = "SELECT korisnik, AES_DECRYPT(sifra, 'sometext'), ime, prezime, pozicija
         FROM tblKorisnici
        WHERE korisnik = ? AND sifra = AES_ENCRYPT(?,'sometext')"
```

I'd also recommend against returning the unencrypted version of `sifra` as this appears to be an authentication check.  If all you need is to determine if a matching record exists you could pare your query down to this:

```
sql = "SELECT 1 FROM tblKorisnici
        WHERE korisnik = ? AND sifra = AES_ENCRYPT(?,'sometext')"
```

Comment: On a side note, from a security stand point pass phrases should be stored in an unrecoverable form such as a one way hashing function, because if you can recover it, then so could a malicious user.

Comment: Good point. sifra is a password field in my application. Thanks for point me to the right direction. I will try to add some 1way hashing function and try to learn salt thing zaph wrote about.